# How to use pointers on structures out of cicle where they were created

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

So i have some cycle where i fill in some structure (through the pointer) and then i copy the pointer to this structure in vector:

```
class Collider
{
   struct Contact
   {
        //Some data here
   };
   vector<Contact*> CollideContacts;
}

XMVECTOR Collider::SomeFunction(....)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SomeValue; i++)
    {
        Contact *SomeContact = new Contact();
        //Then i fill in the Contact structure with some values
        CollideContacts.push_back(SomeContact);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < CollideContacts.size(); i++)
    {
        EllipsMeshCollisionResolution(CollideContacts[i]);
    }
}
```

After filling in the vector i am trying to use it's data in the same function but out of this cycle, as i shown above, and if i do so, i will get some wrong results in my program.

But if i will use this function IN the first cycle i will get correct results:

```
XMVECTOR Collider::SomeFunction(....)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SomeValue; i++)
    {
        Contact *SomeContact = new Contact();
        //Then i fill in the Contact structure with some values
        CollideContacts.push_back(SomeContact);
        EllipsMeshCollisionResolution(SomeContact);
        //or i can also write
        EllipsMeshCollisionResolution(CollideContacts.back());
    }
}
```

But i need to use this function (EllipsMeshCollisionResolution) exactly OUT of the first cycle.
So my question is, maybe i am doing something wrong with the vectors, structures or pointers or something else.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you know you're getting the wrong result in the first case and the right result in the second?

Comment: I tested. In the first case my collision works very bad.(The character collide normal on some sides and move very fast when collliding with others, move through the some sides). But in the second case it works great.

Comment: I mean, what is the expected output? What output do you see in the first case and what output do you see in the second case?

Comment: Well, i havent tested it mathematically yet, but i will. But, as i told, the result on the screen is as i told above. Maybe you know some other approches to use pointer information ouf of the cycle?

Comment: The code you've presented is very simple (you aren't even passing arguments to the constructor of `Contract`). Based on the information you've provided, there shouldn't be a difference between the two version. So either there *isn't* a difference, or you've left out a crucial piece of information (e.g. the definition of `Contract` or of `EllipsMeshCollisionResolution`)

Comment: I'he just found a mistake. You were right - there is no difference between this two versions, and i just needed to test all cycles together with some variables (before that i tested them separately). I indeed lost some variable in my class and it was the culprit of my two-days headache. Thanks very much! :D